# Control when someone tries to print

Tags: c#

Is it possible know when someone is printing a file in Windows using c# with any visual studio library?
I have no idea if its possible and where to start...

What I wanna to do is:  everytime someone tries to print a file in Windows, my c# program execute and update some information in a database.

Comment: write a printer driver?.....

Comment: But is there anyway i can use c# to communicate with that??

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [PrintSpooler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#printer_functions)
Here are some examples of using it:

- [PrintMonitor – A C# print spooler monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2009/08/05/printmonitor-a-c-print-spooler-monitor.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)
- [Monitor jobs in a printer queue (.NET)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET)

You might also run it as Windows Service, so it is always running on background and starts when system starts.